# Get all values from html dictionary attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm using JavaScript.
I have the following HTML element

```
<input name="myInputName" id="myID" type="hidden" 
value='[{"name":"x","value":"1"},{"name":"y","value":"2"}]'>
```

The 'value' attribute contain x,y,z etc...(keys and values)
How can I get only the values from 'value' attribute?

I.e:

```
var allValues = document.getElementById('myID').value;
var values = MyJavaScriptFunction(allValues);//return string: "1,2"
```

Comment: you'll have to loopthrough the array to get values of the key value pair.
1. Get the value attribute (You've achieved it).
2. JSON.parse(value)
3. Iterate over the parsed value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a valid JSON string so parse it using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** and get `value` property using **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method.

```js
var allValues = document.getElementById('myID').value;
var values = JSON.parse(allValues).map(function(v) {
  return v.value;
}).join(); // join array element with `,`

console.log(values)
```

```html
<input name="myInputName" id="myID" type="hidden" value='[{"name":"x","value":"1"},{"name":"y","value":"2"}]'>
```